# Amazon S3 suddenly stopped working with EC2 but working from localhost

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Create folders and upload files to my S3 bucket stopped working.

The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Everything seems to work previously as i did not change anything recently

After days of testing - i see that i am able to create folders in my bucket from localhost but same code doesnt work on the EC2 instance.

I must resolve the issue ASAP.

Thanks
diginotebooks

Answer (score 0):

Does your EC2 instance have a role? If yes, what is this role? Is it possible that someone detached or modified a policy that was attached to it?

[image: See if an instances has a role]

If your instance doesn't have a role, how do you upload files to S3? Using the AWS CLI tools? Same questions for the IAM profile used.

If you did not change anything - are you using the same IAM credentials from the server and localhost? May be related to this.

Just random thoughts...

Comment: Thanks @christophetd - i do not see that my EC2 instance has a role. IAM role is blank - do you see this as issue?

Yes the IAM credentials from the server and localhost is same.